# Keycloak login form - default Security Key with Username&Password as alternative

Tags: authentication, keycloak, webauthn

I have configured my Keycloak Authentication Flow with following Executions: `WebAuthn Passwordless Authenticator`, `Cookie`, `Identity Provider Redirector`, `Username Password Form` as follows:

[image]

When I want to login I see login form with Username&password fields + identity provider button. Clicking "Try Another Way" I can choose between two options `Username and password` and `Security Key`.

**My question is:** Can I setup authentication flow to have Security Key as my default login window and `Username and Password` form as fallback (accessible by clicking `Try Another Way`)?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and as workaround I changed authentication order under user's option in Admin Console:

[image]

This will set 'Security Key' as first authentication's method after providing username during log-in and hide password under 'Try another way' button.

As far as it works there could be option for setting this order globally for every user.